# Application doesn't remind user even the current time is equal to the time that user have set

Tags: c#

I'm making a reminder app. Here is my code:

```
public partial class reminder : Form
    {
        public reminder()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        DateTime? time;
        string t;
        bool b = false;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            time = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            t = time.Value.ToString("HH:mm");
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = true;
            label3.Text = "Set time: " + t;
            b = true;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t = null;
            label3.Text = "Set time: ";
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            b = false;
        }
        System.Timers.Timer timer;
        private void reminder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button2.Enabled = false;
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        }

        private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (b == true)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Hour == time.Value.Hour && DateTime.Now.Minute == time.Value.Minute)
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    button1.Enabled = true;
                    button2.Enabled = false;
                    b = false;
                    try
                    {
                        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
                        player.SoundLocation = "reminder.mp3";
                        player.Play();
                        player.Play();
                        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
                        frm1.TopMost = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is when the system time is equal to the time that user set in program, the program still does nothing, and this is getting frusfrating. What's wrong with my code?

My dateTimePicker1.Format is **"HH:mm"** so **3:00 PM** will be **15:00**. Is this the reason?

Comment: Did you debug it?

Comment: @Amit Of course, that's why I know

Comment: And there are no errors, it runs smoothly

Comment: Do you start the timer somewhere?

Comment: Where your timer started ?

Comment: I followed a tutorial on the Internet, can you show me the better code?

Comment: As two comments have already pointed out, you need to call `timer.Start()` after you create it. Without a call to `Start()`, the timer never starts (duh) and so your `Elapsed` event handler will never be called.